# How to return Injector in subscribtion

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am trying to make a table and when I click on a button, I display new component with injected data below the clicked row. Problem is that I can't return injector in the subscription.

Here is the method which should return Injector for component

```
getInjector(tableRow: ClientItem) {
    const request: GetTestsRequest = { ccaId: tableRow.clientData.ccaId };
    this.treasuryBackendService.getTests(request).pipe(first()).subscribe(value => {
      console.log('test sub', value.tests);
      return Injector.create({
        providers: [{ provide: TestInject, useValue: value.tests, deps: [] }],
        parent: this.injector
      });
    });
    console.log('Here should i return Injector but with values from subscribe');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method should return Observable where you would map value to use value and injector like this:

```
interface FooInterface {
  injector: any;
  value: any;
}

getInjector(tableRow: ClientItem): Observable<FooInterface> {
    const request: GetTestsRequest = { ccaId: tableRow.clientData.ccaId };
    return this.treasuryBackendService.getTests(request).pipe(
      first(),
      map(value => {
        return {
          injector: Injector.create({
            providers: [{ provide: TestInject, useValue: value.tests, deps: [] }],
            parent: this.injector
          },
          value
        }
      })
    )
}
```

right after you call this method and subscribe, you will have your object like

```
this.getInjector(tableRow).subscribe(console.log)
```

will console.log object with value and injector instance.

Because subscription is async, you can't do it your way.